# Claves foráneas en mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Porque se repite el id 1-1 2-2 3-3?
[image]

Al escoger cualquiera de los tres registros que tengo almacenado se ingresa dos veces

[image]

@z1lV3r

```
    CREATE TABLE `compra` (
`idCompra` int(11) NOT NULL,
`idProveedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
`idEmpleado` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tipoComporbante` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`numeroCompra` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`fechaCompra` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`subTotal` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`iva` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`totalC` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`estado` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;


CREATE TABLE `detalle_compra` (
`idCompra` int(11) NOT NULL,
`idMedicamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cantidad` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
`precio` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
`totalFinal` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `medicamento` (
`idMedicamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
`idcategoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
`codigo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`nombreMed` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`descripcion` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
`fechaElaboracion` date DEFAULT NULL,
`fechaVencimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
`stock` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`precioCosto` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`precioVenta` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`utilidad` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`estado` varchar(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-
-- Indices de la tabla `compra`
--
ALTER TABLE `compra`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idCompra`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `numComprobante_UNIQUE` (`numeroCompra`),
ADD KEY `fk_proveedor_ingreso_idx` (`idProveedor`),
ADD KEY `fk_tra_idx` (`idEmpleado`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `detalle_compra`
--
ALTER TABLE `detalle_compra`
ADD KEY `fk_ingreso_idx` (`idCompra`),
ADD KEY `fk_articulo_idx` (`idMedicamento`);

- Filtros para la tabla `detalle_compra`
--
ALTER TABLE `detalle_compra`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_articulo` FOREIGN KEY (`idMedicamento`) REFERENCES `medicamento` (`idMedicamento`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ingreso` FOREIGN KEY (`idCompra`) REFERENCES `compra` (`idCompra`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: No miro donde estableces como llave primaria y única  el idMedicamento

Answer (score 2):

He copiado tu codigo y no me ha generado ningun inconveniente.
Si has configurado tu gestor de base de datos, es preferible que lo dejes por default o cambies de nuevo a los ajustes previos si es el caso.

He probado el codigo y creo las tablas sin probles, inserte sin novedad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fijate aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo extraño es que te muestre select para insertar el valor

Prueba este codigo haber si te genera un cambio:

```
--
-- Base de datos: `app_staroverflow`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `compra`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compra` (
  `idCompra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idProveedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idEmpleado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipoComporbante` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numeroCompra` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fechaCompra` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subTotal` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iva` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalC` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `detalle_compra`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detalle_compra` (
  `idCompra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idMedicamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `totalFinal` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `medicamento`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `medicamento` (
  `idMedicamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idcategoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreMed` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fechaElaboracion` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fechaVencimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precioCosto` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precioVenta` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utilidad` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `compra`
--
ALTER TABLE `compra`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idCompra`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `detalle_compra`
--
ALTER TABLE `detalle_compra`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idCompra`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `medicamento`
--
ALTER TABLE `medicamento`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idMedicamento`);
```

Comment: Podria ser una buena respuesta si le especificas al OP lo que has agregado al código, como lo es el designar como llave primaria el campo idMedicamento en la tabla medicamento.

Comment: Gracias por responder pero el campo (idCompra) de la tabla detalle_compra  es foreign key que referencia la a primary key de la tabla compra